# how to change the verbose_name or use original field name in django-taggit tag field

Tags: django-taggit, verbose, field-names

I am using [`django-taggit`](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit) for one of my projects and as per the documentation I did the following in the model that i want to use tags / keywords in.

#### models.py

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    description = models.TextField()
    keywords = TaggableManager()
```

I am using a `ModelForm` form for the above model and the `label`'s text for the `keywords` field shows up as `"Tags"` instead of `"Keywords"`.

How can i have `django-taggit` use the original field name ??

Answer (score 4):

Just opened up the TaggableManager definition to check this.

```py
class TaggableManager(RelatedField):
    def __init__(self, verbose_name=_("Tags"),
    help_text=_("A comma-separated list of tags."), through=None, blank=False):
```

So to set the verbose_name simply initialize the manager as:

```py
TaggableManager(verbose_name="keywords")
```